# Whether to use a comma or not

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have been looking at many company description and I found the following two usages

> a) We sell a diverse range of products from books to toys.
>
> b) We sell a diverse range of products, from books to toys.

The thing that puzzles me is why many companies insert a ',' before from.

Please let me know which one is correct. If b) is correct, I am curious why so?

Answer (score 1):

Although commas are not necessarily needed to separate prepositional phrases, option B would be preferred in a formal context, as it reflects are more natural word rhythm. The comma also serves to clarify the sentence a little: as one reads option A, one may think, before completing the sentence, that the "from" will tell the location of the company (so from where it's selling these products: "We sell a diverse range of products from our first location, while the second site is more limited").

In short, option B, with the comma, is preferred stylistically and to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you say the sentence, you find you take a small breather between 'products' and 'from'. This is why we write the comma.

Comment: Thanks. So is it ok grammatically if I stick with option a) of without comma?

Comment: I agree about the 'breather'  As with parentheses, the part of the sentence before the comma can stand alone  -  "We sell a diverse range of products." while the rest *could* be added using a comma, a dash or parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I still wonder if option'(a) in my question is grammatically correct? Also, good point about the dash and prentheses

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that I also think it's fine without the comma.  The whole sentence is simple enough that there's no ambiguity.